# What is the global setting for Navigator "Link with editor" in Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse Helios with CDT 7. I want to set the global preference for the "Link with editor" in Navigator to true. I want to know the property name for this setting. I have searched all the pref files in workspace, but couldn't find.
Is there anything like "org.eclipse.ui.navigate.linkWithEditor"?

Where does Eclipse stores this setting in workspace?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following setting in .ini file is working for global

```
org.eclipse.ui/LINK_NAVIGATOR_TO_EDITOR=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferences (one file per plugin) are stored under `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`. If I grep for `link` in that directory, I find it hits in the JDT and Groovy plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply lulion Dragos. But I have searched .prefs files before, couldn't find anything for this Navigator setting . I found "Link to editor" for Outline setting in .prefs, which is "org.eclipse.cdt.ui.outline.linktoeditor=true". Can you please give me the proeperty and value? is it "org.eclipse.ui.navigate.linkWithEditor=true"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the noise.